# List based on right Kan extension

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In the ``[Kan Extensions for Program Optimisation](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/Kan.pdf)'' by Ralf Hinze there is the definition of List type based on right Kan extension of the forgetful functor from the category of monoids along itself (section 7.4). The paper gives Haskell implementation as follows:

```
newtype List a = Abstr {
  apply :: forall z . (Monoid z) => (a -> z) -> z
  }
```

I was able to define usual nil and cons constructors:

```
nil :: List a
nil = Abstr (\f -> mempty)

cons :: a -> List a -> List a
cons x (Abstr app) = Abstr (\f -> mappend (f x) (app f))
```

With the following instance of Monoid class for Maybe functor, I managed to define head function:

```
instance Monoid (Maybe a) where
  mempty = Nothing
  mappend Nothing m = m
  mappend (Just a) m = Just a

head :: List a -> Maybe a
head (Abstr app) = app Just
```

**Question**: How can one define tail function?

Comment: For what it's worth, your `Monoid` instance for `Maybe` is typically provided with the newtype `Data.Monoid.First`.

Comment: That's a common pitfall without any obvious solution. A version, that traverses the whole list, was discussed somewhere in the TAPL book. For a better version see [this](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/Boehm-Berarducci.html). Also, there is a [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist) with FoldMap lists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a rather principled solution to implementing head and tail in one go ([full gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/ef7330d74161c46a401b)):

First of all, we know how to append lists (it will be useful later on):

```
append :: List a -> List a -> List a
append (Abstr xs) (Abstr ys) = Abstr (\ f -> xs f <> ys f)
```

Then we introduce a new type `Split` which we will use to detect whether a `List` is empty or not (and get, in the case it's non empty, a head and a tail):

```
newtype Split a = Split { outSplit :: Maybe (a, List a) }
```

This new type forms a monoid: indeed we know how to append two lists.

```
instance Monoid (Split a) where
  mempty = Split Nothing
  mappend (Split Nothing)        (Split nns)            = Split nns
  mappend (Split mms)            (Split Nothing)        = Split mms
  mappend (Split (Just (m, ms))) (Split (Just (n, ns))) =
    Split $ Just (m, append ms (cons n ns))
```

Which means that we can get a function from `List a` to `Split a` using `List a`'s `apply`:

```
split :: List a -> Split a
split xs = apply xs $ \ a -> Split $ Just (a, nil)
```

`head` and `tail` can finally be trivially derived from `split`:

```
head :: List a -> Maybe a
head = fmap fst . outSplit . split

tail :: List a -> Maybe (List a)
tail = fmap snd . outSplit . split
```

Comment: This doesn't work for "middle-infinite" lists as discussed in my answer, does it? In fact it doesn't seem to work for infinite lists at all.

Comment: I believe that the monad we get from the adjunction is precisely the one of finite lists, no?

Comment: You and roconnor both. :-) I'd be interested in a solution that worked well for infinite lists, both because that's the type that you actually end up with in Haskell, and because termination in the infinite case can correspond to efficiency in the finite case (traversing the whole structure just to take its tail isn't ideal). This solution creates quite a few unnecessary memptys.

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure that that's the monad you get from the adjunction in the case of *Haskell*, depending on what exactly the categories you're working with there are.

Comment: @shachaf wouldn't you need `mappend` to be non-strict in the second arg, eg by adding a left zero to `Monoid`, `z <> _ = z; m <> z = m`

Answer (score 10):

This implementation of lists as free monoids is provided in the package [`fmlist`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist), which notes some interesting properties of it (unlike most implementations of lists, which are right-biased, this one is truly unbiased; you can make an arbitrary tree, and although of course the monoid laws force you to see it as flattened, you can still observe some differences in the infinite case. This is almost a Haskell quirk -- usually, free monoids). It also has an implementation of `tail`, so that's sort of an answer to your question (but see below).

With these sorts of representations (not just this particular one one, but also e.g. `forall r. (a -> r -> r) -> r -> r` lists), there are usually some operations (e.g. appending) that become easier, and some (e.g. zip and tail) that become more difficult. This is discussed a bit in various places, e.g. [How to take the `tail` of a functional stream](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/Boehm-Berarducci.html#cdr-fstream).

Looking more closely at `fmlist`, though, its solution is pretty unsatisfactory: It just converts the nice balanced tree that you give it to a right-biased list using `foldr`, which allows it to do regular list operations, but loses the monoidal structure. The tail of a "middle-infinite" list is no longer "middle-infinite", it's just right-infinite like a regular list.

It should be possible to come up with a clever `Monoid` instance to compute the tail while disturbing the rest of the structure as little as possible, but an obvious one doesn't come to mind off-hand. I can think of a non-clever "brute force" solution, though: Cheat and reify the "list" into a tree using an invalid `Monoid` instance, inspect the tree, and then fold it back up so the end result is valid. Here's what it would look like with my [`nonfree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/nonfree) package and `fmlist`:

```
nail :: FM.FMList a -> FM.FMList a
nail (FM.FM k) = FM.FM $ \f -> foldMap f (nail' (k N))

nail' :: N a -> N a
nail' NEmpty = error "nail' NEmpty"
nail' (N x) = NEmpty
nail' (NAppend l r) =
  case normalize l of
    NEmpty -> nail' r
    N x -> r
    l' -> NAppend (nail' l') r

-- Normalize a tree so that the left side of a root NAppend isn't an empty
-- subtree of any shape. If the tree is infinite in a particular way, this
-- won't terminate, so in that sense taking the tail of a list can make it
-- slightly worse (but you were already in pretty bad shape as far as
-- operations on the left side are concerned, and this is a pathological case
-- anyway).
normalize :: N a -> N a
normalize (NAppend l r) =
  case normalize l of
    NEmpty -> normalize r
    l' -> NAppend l' r
normalize n = n
```