# How to get last items of infinite list concatenated with finite list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, how to efficiently get the last item(s) of an infinite list concatenated with a finite list?

`last` does not work, it obviously iterates from the head, so the following never finishes:

```
-- let's have a list of all natural numbers,
-- with zero appended
arr = [1..] ++ [0]
-- it was fast! now get the last item, should be easy
res = last arr
```

**EDIT**: I wonder what is the Haskell's internal representation of `[1..] ++ [0]`, is it initially "totally unevaluated"? If it would **internally** represent it like a "sequence" of two (unevaluated) lists, the `last` function could just get the last item of the last item, immediately.

Comment: An infinite list concatenated with a finite list is infinite the same way the first list is infinite. List are not ordinal numbers, there's no different kinds of infinities there. There is no last element in `[1..]++[0]`.

Comment: I'm adding a quiestion, which might clear why I am asking that question..

Comment: Please add all info relevant to this question to the question itself.

Comment: Haskell is cool -- but it doesn't do transfinite ordinals -- *without* you doing the necessary work of deciding how to represent them and writng functions to work with them.

Comment: An infinite list concatenated with a finite list - is infinite list. While at the infinite list you can`t get the final (last) element, it is his property.

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks for naming the problem, whatever that name means.. :) so, .. who does them (transfinite ordinals), and why don't you make a regular answer? I might get it: it might be LONG

Comment: the last element of a list which is one element longer than infinity... what is it, you ask? yes, when you "define" such a list you refer to that element, but *is* it really the last element of a list which has no last element at all, being infinite? You do *not* in fact define a list which is one element longer than infinity; but just a list that is infinite.

Comment: Regarding your edit, why should the internal representation accommodate mathematically undefined lists? If you want to make up a definition for appending to an infinite list, you can do so yourself; don't expect the language to anticipate your definition.

Comment: @chepner, appending itself obviously was not the problem.

Comment: You can do this with [`FMList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist-0.9/docs/Data-FMList.html)s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever the internal representation of an append operation `++` is, it has to conform to the language definition.

[Haskell 2010 Language Report specifies](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-22900020.1):

> `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`
>
> Append two lists, i.e.,
>
> ```
>   [x1, ..., xm] ++ [y1, ..., yn] == [x1, ..., xm, y1, ..., yn]   
>   [x1, ..., xm] ++ [y1, ...] == [x1, ..., xm, y1, ...]
> ```
>
> If the first list is not finite, the result is the first list.

Yes, you could try to define it differently, like some bona fide object in memory  holding its argument lists, responding to different requests like `head` or `last` in specific ways, aiming to get the law of

```
last (xs ++ ys) == last ys
```

to hold; but that is just not Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

You can't in general find “Haskell's internal representation” for any expression. The Haskell standard defines no such thing as an internal representation; it's up to the compiler to choose one.

In a naïve implementation, `[1..] ++ [0]` would sure enough be represented as a thunk pointing to two different lists. However, no matter how many elements you pop off the result, you will always take from the first, infinite list (the standard does guarantee *that*). So the compiler is perfectly free to optimise the `++ [0]` away altogether, because it can provenly make no difference to the outcome.

If you actually need to store multiple lists of possibly infinite length and access the head of more than one of them, well, make it explicit! For instance just use a nested list `[[1..], [0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Haskell are left-biased, so in order to get the last element of a list you have to traverse the whole spine, but [lists defined as free monoids](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist-0.9/docs/Data-FMList.html) are unbiased and hence

```
last $ fromList [1..] `append` fromList [0]
```

computes to `0`. But such lists have their own [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381133/list-based-on-right-kan-extension).